# Any way to redirect SSL request on Apache from one server to another?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, configuration

I have 1 wild card SSL certificate for 1 domain. But I have multiple servers on sub-domains (server1.domain.com, server2.domain.com etc).

It's only working on the server.domain.com but not on server1.domain.com and server2.domain.com and others.

Is, there any way to fix this and use 1 SSL cert (wildcard for 1 domain) for various servers (hardware)

> i.e. if a request for ssl comes on
>   server1.domain.com or
>   server2.domain.com, the request is
>   routed to server.domain.com

Thanks

Error: It says SSL not found in the log file.

I have got this message from my supprt:

> You will need to purchase another
>   wildcard ssl as the ssl will only
>   certify one server per ssl.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, to secure all your sub-domains under wild card certificates it must on same server. If you want to secure other server's domain you will need to have another certificate.

Comment: is there some apache mod which redirects the ssl request to primary server?

Answer (score 0):

if it is really a wildcard certificate, for `*.domain.com`, it should work for server1.domain.com, even if it is hosted on another continent. You simply have to copy the server certificate to the other continent (which seams missing from your short log extract).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like whoever you bought the certificate from is complaining that you should buy a different certificate for each server.  I have never heard of this, and it sounds like some licensing thing rather than any technical limitation, then again I could be wrong.

You should be able to copy your SSL WildCard Certificate and import it to a new server.

It looks like you can look in your httpd.conf on your web server, and locate the SSL Certificate lines inside your "VirtualHost" blocks.

It will look something like

```
<VirtualHost 999.999.999.999:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/example
ServerName www.example.com
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /certs/example_certFile.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /certs/example_certKey.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /certs/chainFile.crt #if needed
</VirtualHost>
```

Copy the CertificateFile, KeyFile, and Chain File if it exists, and move it to your other server.  Then setup the "VirtualHost" block on your other server the same way.